# Copy iTunes playlists to external USB flash drive

Tags: itunes

I have lots of playlists on my iTunes library, and I want to be able to copy the music of certain playlists to a flash drive to play on a stereo system. I have too many songs in too many folders to just copy the raw .mp3 files, so that option is out. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I miss something, you can just [drag & drop the playlist](http://lifehacker.com/281055/drag-and-drop-an-itunes-playlists-songs-into-a-folder) to your USB drive.

Comment: I don't know why, but I couldn't the first time. I decided to try again, and it just started copying :S I have no idea what changed

Answer (score 1):

[iTunesExport](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/dev/itunesexport/) is a Java program that you can use to export iTunes playlists including the music files to a specific directory or drive.

If you regularly want to export iTunes playlists the iTunesExport command line version makes it easy to create bash scripts you can reuse.